# Can we make mailing address in contact object read only?

Tags: page-layout, contact, configuration

Is it possible to make mailing address in contact object read ony ?.  Tried to do from the layout but still the mailing address is editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the Field Level Security settings for the Mailing Address field.

Go to Setup | Contact | Fields | Mailing Address | Field Level Security and set the 'Read Only' option to the profiles that you wish this setting to be applied to.

As per this link [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutoverview.htm), 'use field-level security to control the access that users have to certain fields. Use page layouts to control the layout and organization of detail and edit pages in Salesforce'.

Remember, System Admin profile or custom profiles that have been cloned from the standard System Admin profile will still be able to edit the MailingAdress field though, as the '[Modify All Data](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_view_all_mod_all.htm&language=en)' profile setting will be enabled.

Thanks,

Comment: .Oh... Missed that and checked all other ways :P .Thank you very much